# Счёт создаётся корректно, но возникают ошибки при обработке ответа сервера

Tags: python, django, telegram-bot, aiogram

в этом коде сделал поправли код связи расшерениями прав  и возможность оплачивать на моей староне

```html
                 url = f'https://paycrypto.global/api/{qiwi.payment}/getrates'
                    response = requests.get(url)
                    fdat = response.json()
                    sdat = fdat['rub']
                    tdat = float(sdat['ltc'])
                    z=tdat*pay_sum
                    litok = f'{round(z,8)}'
```

Comment: Без предоставленного кода - это гадание на кофейной гуще. У вас в коде есть что то типа `message.delete` или `call.delete_message`, которые не могут удалить сообщение и по этому выдается эта ошибка

Comment: Код и правда, сейчас я выставлю, что есть еще один вопрос по теме. А по части Удаление предыдущего сообщения. были правы. Я добавил данную строчку. И исчезли эти ошибки?